# How can I check if a python file is ran by a user or not?

Tags: python, file

I created a **python** file named`wizard.py` and in that file, I wanted to check if the file > `wizard.py` is already run by a user or not.

if not > run it, if it is >  print a statement.

Is there a way to do it?. Thanks in the future!

*using python

Comment: You could have the script write a marker into another file, then see whether that file exists; if so, the script has been run.

Comment: Don't understand what a marker is.

Comment: Anything: you could write an empty file to indicate the script has been run. If the (empty) file is not there, the script hasn't run.

Comment: It does sound as if you're trying to solve another problem using a run-once script, for which there is likely a better solution than this. For example, you may be trying to prevent writing double output to a file, which should generally be solved differently. So you may want to rethink your actual problem and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy way)

```
import psutil   

my_script_name='my_script.py'

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    
    boolFind=any([x for x in process.cmdline() if my_script_name in x])
    if boolFind:

            '''         
                your code
            
            '''
```

Comment: Never use `try: except:` – it will be impossible to debug anything within it since all exceptions are swallowed. Also, `any()` instead of `bool`...

Comment: In addition, this is likely not what OP wants – this only figures out whether the script is running at the same moment.

Comment: I focused on part of the question "is already runned or not" Yes, I agree, I do not fully know his (RgTheGreat) working environment and the essence of his task

Comment: escaped the access check, so "try" AKX, very much for u comment, i will know more )